# How do i know if an event is an all day meeting? (Google Calendar)

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

In the event documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) it says that the start.date field will be poplulated if an event is an all-day event. But when i create an all-day meeting and then query it with the [https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendar}/events/{event}](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%7Bcalendar%7D/events/%7Bevent%7D) url the start and end responses dont have a date field, they come back as:

```
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2022-08-25T00:00:00+01:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/London"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2022-08-26T00:00:00+01:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/London"
 },
```

Picture from the documentation below

[image]

Update:

I'm creating a meeting on my calendar, selecting all day then adding a room.

[image]

I'm then querying this event using the https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/ page. Here i'm putting in my calendar (my email) and the event id. The correct event is returned but the start and end dates come back as this:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When I tried to replicate this, all-day events, whether created from the UI or via API, included `start.date` and `end.date`, even if the event has a meeting attached to it. Are you sure this is an all-day event, and not a timed event? If that's the case, can you provide a set of reproduction steps for this, including how are you creating the event?

Comment: @Iamblichus Thanks for getting back to me i have added further details to the main post.

Answer (score 2):

#### This might be a bug:

All-day [events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events) containing a room don't include `start.date` and `end.date` fields, even though these should be populated in all-day events, according to the docs:

> **start.date**: The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.

#### Issue Tracker:

I went ahead and filed an issue in Issue Tracker:

- [All-day events containing a room don't include date field](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244387266)

Consider [starring this issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of it and to help prioritizing it.